# Find operator that produce a given amplitude

Tags: operators, spinors, correlation-functions, helicity

While I was studying spinor helicity formalism, in many articles, it gives the operators that produce a given amplitude. Is there a generic method of finding operators that produce a given amplitude?

After some research, an example I found is in https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.15849 page 12. They write field strength operator in spinor helicity formalism and match that with the amplitude. But it does not work if I don't know which operator produces a given amplitude. Also, I don't know what I should do if I have a denominator (like $\frac{\text{something}}{[31]^3}$).

---

For example, a given amplitude:
$$A_3(-1,-1,-1)=\left<12\right>\left<13\right>\left<23\right>$$
which is derive just using little group scaling (not from any given Lagrange).

In article, it says dimension 6 operator $\text{Tr} F^\mu_{\;\nu} F^\nu_{\;\lambda} F^\lambda_{\;\mu}$ produces such an amplitude. It is easy to verify that, but I don't know how to derive it.

In general, I want to know whether there is a generic method to find the operators that produce any given amplitude.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Maybe write up some equations for what exactly you mean?

Comment: @Codename47 example added.